# count the number of words in a particular xml node using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

In some scenario I need to calculate the number of words in a particular node.
   Consider the following xml document.

```
<root>
<mainNode>     
<book>      
<price> 100 </price>     
<city> chennai </city>    
<list>      
<language> c java ruby </language>    
</list>  
</book> 

<book>     
<price> 200 </price>     
<city> banglore </city>     
<list>           
<language> c java </language>       
</list>     
<list>           
<language> c++ java </language>       
</list>     
<list>
<language> pascal java </language>       
</list>
</book>  

<book>   
<price> 300 </price>    
<city> delhi </city>     
<list>         
<language> java ruby </language>     
</list>   
</book>

</mainNode>
</root>
```

In the above document I need to count the number of languages in the "language" node.

The Output like **Count::11**

How do I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your sample, all the languages are padded with spaces in the text

```
<language> c java ruby </language>
```

Can you assume this will always be the case, or will you get **language** elements like so?

```
<language>c java ruby</language>
```

In this case, concatenating all the language elements would result in a string like this, which shows seven words

```
c java rubyc javac++ javapascal javajava ruby
```

To cope with this situation, you will probably need to match on the language element, and return a string which is always followed by a space.

Try this XSLT...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="languagelist">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="//language"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <!-- Count the number of words by counting the number of spaces -->
      Count:<xsl:value-of select="string-length($languagelist) - string-length(translate($languagelist, ' ', ''))" />
   </xsl:template>

   <!-- Return the normalised string with one space at the end -->
   <xsl:template match="language">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(.), ' ')" />
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the method to count the number of words is to compare the length of the normalised string (with single spaces) with the length of the string with no spaces. (i.e count the number of spaces)